# CSS Transitions not working inside parametrized functions

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

So I got the following code to create a simple fixed red box:

```
var red_box = document.createElement('div');
    red_box.id = 'caixa_apresentacao_texto';
    red_box.style.width = "40%";
    red_box.style.overflow = "hidden";
    red_box.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    red_box.style.color = "black";
    red_box.style.border = "5px double red";

    /* Centralizing */
    red_box.style.position = "fixed";
    red_box.style.left = "50%";
    red_box.style.marginLeft = "-20%";      //Por que a largura é 40%...

    red_box.style.transition = "max-height 1s";
    red_box.style.display = "none";
    red_box.style.zIndex = "99999999999999";
    red_box.style.marginTop = "50px";
    red_box.style.maxHeight = "0px";

   document.documentElement.insertBefore(red_box,document.body);
```

So, the idea is that, when I pass some text to this box, it enlarges slowly in order to display it. I get this behaviour with the following code:

```
var timerHeight;

function expandBox(text){
    clearInterval(timerHeight);

    /* if the box is empty...*/
    if(document.querySelector("#red_box").style.maxHeight == "0px"){   

        document.querySelector("#red_box").style.display = "inline-block";
        red_box.innerHTML = text;

        /* Call a function that enlarge the maxHeight property , theorically with the transition letting it more beautiful */
        var someText = "text";
        timerHeight= setTimeout(enlargeBoxHeight(someText),1);
    }
}

function enlargeBoxHeight(anyText){
    document.querySelector("#red_box").style.maxHeight ="50px";
}       

expandBox("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sollicitudin euismod metus, at blandit neque maximus ac. Integer fermentum nulla at nibh suscipit, a placerat est pretium. Morbi varius ornare enim, ac pulvinar elit aliquet in. Nullam non diam in nibh consectetur fringilla id nec enim. Mauris lacinia a augue ac consectetur. Etiam tempor et elit a dictum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam interdum pulvinar pharetra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam non diam eget turpis tincidunt venenatis at in est. Duis laoreet nibh ultrices erat faucibus hendrerit.")
```

You can see the fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1624v2d1/2/).

So, I know that 50px is not a good height, but what matters here is that **the transition is not working**. You may have noticed that the var `someText` is useless here; but it does have the purpose to express my doubt. I've tried to take it off of the `enlargeBoxHeight` call. So the last part of the code now is:

```
...
        timerHeight= setTimeout(enlargeBoxHeight,1);
    }
}

function enlargeBoxHeight(){
    document.querySelector("#red_box").style.maxHeight ="50px";
}   

expandBox("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut sollicitudin euismod metus, at blandit neque maximus ac. Integer fermentum nulla at nibh suscipit, a placerat est pretium. Morbi varius ornare enim, ac pulvinar elit aliquet in. Nullam non diam in nibh consectetur fringilla id nec enim. Mauris lacinia a augue ac consectetur. Etiam tempor et elit a dictum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam interdum pulvinar pharetra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aliquam non diam eget turpis tincidunt venenatis at in est. Duis laoreet nibh ultrices erat faucibus hendrerit.")
```

And the surprise: **the transition works now**. Why? What I am missing here?

Comment: You're going to drive yourself insane managing the styles in the Javascript like this. You're **much** better off putting this in CSS and toggling a class as you change the text.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds good! But I'm still curious about this behaviour...

Comment: Basically, `setTimeout(foo(), 500)` will not wait the half a second, but `setTimeout(foo, 500)` will. The first runs the function immediately. You'd need to do `setTimeout(foo.bind(this, someArgument), 500);` to pass an argument, but `setTimeout(function () { foo(someArgument); }, 500)` would work just as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do:

```
setTimeout(enlargeBoxHeight,1);
```

Without the parentheses `()`, you pass the ***function*** `enlargeBoxHeight` to the timeout, without calling it yet. The timeout will call it after 1ms. Which produced expected behavior + transition.

When you do:

```
timerHeight= setTimeout(enlargeBoxHeight(someText),1);
```

You pass the ***result*** of the function `enlargeBoxHeight` to the timeout. `()` part forces javascript to immediately call the function, and process everything before the timeout. So the transition does not work. After the 1ms, javascript handles the result (with is undefined or irrelevant).

If you want to pass a parameter to a timeout, do:

```
timerHeight= setTimeout(enlargeBoxHeight.bind(someText),1);
```

Which should work as expected.

Comment: Think you want `.bind(this, someText)`.